# event ID, event binding switch-like

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jquery, backbone-events

is there an id for each fired event?

I am yet to dig into events, for now i have a view (div) with some buttons, a click on the div itself should do the same as a click on one of the buttons.
When i click on any button, the event elevates and the function that bind to 'click div' also called.

For a quick fix that i did, i save the event object and on 'click div' i check if the calle event is the same that i saved, then do nothing.
What is the better way to do this? 
And also i cant find ids in events, are there any and can they be added to the event object?

```
if( arguments ){
    if( arguments[0] ){ // jquery event
        if( this.lastEvent == arguments[0] ){ //already processed event
            return;
        }
        this.lastEvent = arguments[0];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
as suggested - what id did, in view:

```
events: {
    'click .btn-mark-saw': 'mark_saw',
    'click .btn-mark-circle': 'mark_circle',
    'click':'mark_circle'
},
mark_saw: function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    //...
    this.render();

},
mark_circle: function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    //...
    this.render();
},
```

it works, thank you!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it sounds like you want `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent a button click from triggering the div click.

Comment: no, i need the right events binding / other right way to do it, like 'click .button','click .button2', 'click div:not(.buttons)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should serve your purpose.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#divID").live("click", function(){
      //div click action..
  });
  $("#buttonID").live("click", function(event){
      //button click action..
      event.stopPropagation();

  });
});
```

Thanks..